# Ubuntu 20.04 takes a lot of time to unlock

Tags: suspend, lock-screen, unlock

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 a couple months ago and just recently when I try to wake my computer from suspension and type in the password the screen freezes for at least a minute but the cursor keeps working. It would be really helpful if someone can help me avoid this.

Comment: are there a lot of programs running when you suspend, or do you have many folders showning on the desktop?

Comment: I would say there are usually about 3-5 applications(spotify, web browser, file manager) running. And I don't have any folder or icon on my desktop

Comment: Post the out of journalctl in your question. It might reveal some problem ... Since it is very verbose, just post the log around the time of the wakeup

Comment: If you need to, you can post logs on https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and post the link in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete and clean up your os from garbage and unnecessary files.
You should also check that any startup application which can be heavy to load or you have set more applications to startup as the os loads.

I have written a python script to clean os.
here is the repo link check it up [Cleaner](https://github.com/jspw/Cleaner)

You can also use gui apps like spacer.
install : `sudo apt install stacer`

run : `stacer`

you can check the starup applications using stacer

Comment: I coudn't find spacer, do you mean stacer?

Comment: yes ! i'm sorry it was a type mistake !

Comment: Thanks! It takes a couple of seconds now. Also, Should I remove cache on a daily basis?

Comment: No you can remove once in one or two months.
You can have a look on  my cleaner script in github and profile :3

Comment: Okay! Thank you.